# Use string as SASS mixin argument separator

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, mixins

I've seen SASS mixing examples like so:

```
@include width(2 of 12);
```

How is that string separator achieved? In my mixin it looks like this:

```
@mixin width($span, $total) {
  ...
}
```